# How to populate global variable with Python joblib?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables, joblib

I want to run some code in parallel and populate a global variable with the results in **Python**. I have written an example code to check the behavior of **joblib**, but I don't know how to get the results back. The example code is:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

global_var = np.zeros(10)

def populate(idx):
   print('I am core',idx,'\')
   global_var[idx] = idx

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(populate)(idx) for idx in range(len(global_var))`
```

if I check global_var before running anything else, it is an array of zeros; when I run the code, the array is full of "None" values.

**How can I return the values from the function and populate the global array?**

Thank you very much in advance! =)

Answer (score 11):

I know it's an old thread but it might interest others to know that **THIS IS POSSIBLE**!

Add `require='sharedmem'` to the Parallel initialization.
You can read [this link](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) for more examples about parallelization loops.

---

So in your example:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

global_var = np.zeros(10)

def populate(idx):
   print('I am core',idx,'\'')
   global_var[idx] = idx

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, require='sharedmem')(delayed(populate)(idx) for idx in range(len(global_var)))

print(global_var)
```

> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]

Comment: Thanks, bro. you've saved my day.

Comment: FYI this uses the threading backend which defeats the purpose of paralleism in most cases in Python

Comment: great solution, but the runtime is now almost identical to the runtime with no parallelism

Comment: What about passing global_var as a parameter, if only read is needed? Like `delayed(populate)(idx, global_var)`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't do it this way: you'll need to specify a backend with shared memory, or manually create a shared memory. This is a little bit more involved (but covered by the documentation).

Here, the easiest way to achieve it is to define your function such that it returns the result of its computation, and then you process these results (returned by the call to `Parallel(..)(..)` in the main process (after the line starting with `Parallel`).